# setTransform not a function for transform prop on SaveButton

Tags: javascript, react-admin

I am utilizing react-admin for forms and I am trying to change the data once the user presses accept/reject; I am trying to use the transform prop on the SaveButton, but it gives the Type error 'setTransform is not a function'. What is a workaround for this? Here is what it looks like currently:

```
<SaveButton
   redirect = "list"
   label = "Approve"
   transform = {(data) => ({...data, approval: true})}
/>
```

Comment: I suspect you have a custom form for this. Can you share the form code and where it is used?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `transform` function is meant to return an object, you have a syntax error. It should be:

```
<SaveButton
   redirect = "list"
   label = "Approve"
   transform = {(data) => ({...data, approval: true})}
/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I typed it incorrectly earlier and edited my post to reflect this change; it is still returning the same error.